# Datareader Unable to read URL

Tags: python-3.x, yahoo-finance, datareader

Trying to access stock prices for 'AAPL', 'GOOG', 'MFST', 'AMZN'

```
from pandas_datareader import data
from datetime import datetime

tech_list = ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'MFST', 'AMZN']
end = datetime.now()
start = datetime(end.year-1,end.month,end.day)

for stock in tech_list:
    globals()[stock] = data.DataReader(stock,'google', start, end)
```

Getting an error
RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=AAPL&startdate=Jan+30%2C+2017&enddate=Jan+30%2C+2018&output=csv

Can someone help me in what is been done wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Google doesn't allow it. Opening the URL in the web browser shows an explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative to google finance api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040954/alternative-to-google-finance-api)

Comment: Thanks @mkrieger1, I kind off realised my import was not proper
it should have been "import pandas_datareader.data as web"
instead of
"from pandas_datareader import data"

This change worked for me. Also I Used Yahoo instead of Google